# Is it possible to force a post to one server behind a load balancer?

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, post, load-balancing

We have a set up of two web servers behind a load balancer. The two servers are sync'd using lsyncd. web 1 being the master server, web 2 being the slave

The issue is if someone is on web2 and they upload a picture file it is not transferred to web1.

Is it possible to make it so all form posts go to web1, when behind the load balancer? Possibly in htaccess?

Comment: Yes this is possible. What efforts have you put forth to achieve this

Comment: I have discussed with our server support, they have recommended that I basically post all of our files onto a cloud server. I am able to do this but it is a huge amount of coding to restructure our entire picture system. I am looking for a more elegant way of doing this. I suppose I could just post to our server ip behind the load balancer. I didn't really want to put the direct server ip in the form post.